# how to send response immediately from rest api when it triggers a job in the backend?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I need to trigger a job using the api, I dont want the api give response only after the completion of job, would like to respond back with "your job has been created" and let the job run in the backend and complete after couple of minutes.

As am newbie to jaxrs, I couldn't able to find solution to this problem. All i can see is send a 201 response. yes but how?

Below is the code am using :

```
@Path("{triggerjob}")
public Response ClassA {
ClassB objB = new ClassB();
objB.methodOne(jsonObject);
//what to do for response message as soon as job submitted?
return Response.status(201).build();
}

public void Class B {
ClassC objC = new ClassC();
objC.methodOne(jsonObject); //This triggers the job and job runs for 1/2 hour
}
```

So the classB will be return to Class A only after the job is completed, I would like to the user to know that the job is triggered and will be completed after half hour.
How to achieve this? How to jump to return statement and provide the update to the user who triggered this job?

Comment: Call `objB.methodOne()` asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

You should run your job in async way.

For example via EJB @Asynchronous

```java
@Stateless
public class B  {
    @Asynchronous
    public void doAsynchronousWork() {

    }
}
```

By the way for the http response the best response code here would be  `202 accepted`